# How can I find MIN value for each group and select the full row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a PROJECTS table with PROJECT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, COMPANY_ID and COST columns.
One customer could have one or several projects in different companies. 
What I want is to choose a customer, who generates the smallest income for each company.

**For example** if the table looks like this

```
project_id customer_id company_id cost
         1           1          1 1000
         2           1          1  100
         3           2          1 3000
         4           1          2  300
         5           2          2  100
```

, the expected answer is:

(COMPANY_ID) 1 | (CUSTOMER_ID) 1 | (COST) 1100

(COMPANY_ID) 2 | (CUSTOMER_ID) 2 | (COST) 100

Because the first customer generates 1000 + 100 = 1100 in total.

**My query looks like this:**

```
SELECT TABLE1.company_id, TABLE1.customer_id, MIN(profit)

FROM (
            SELECT company_id, customer_id, SUM(projects.cost) AS profit

            FROM projects

            GROUP BY company_id,customer_id

     ) AS TABLE1

GROUP BY TABLE1.company_id;
```

It counts the MIN profit, but the ID's in CUSTOMER_ID column are always wrong. How can I build a connection between customers' IDs and their total profit for each company? Is it possible?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: JOIN the table with the current derived table (aka sub-query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for doing this is a "hack", because it uses string operations to get the value you want:

```
SELECT cc.company_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(cc.customer_id ORDER BY profit ASC), ',', 1) as customer_id,
       MIN(profit)
FROM (SELECT p.company_id, p.customer_id, SUM(p.cost) AS profit
      FROM projects p
      GROUP BY p.company_id, p.customer_id
     ) cc
GROUP BY cc.company_id;
```

An alternative in MySQL is something like this:

```
SELECT p.company_id, p.customer_id, SUM(p.cost) AS profit
FROM projects p
GROUP BY p.company_id, p.customer_id
HAVING SUM(p.cost) = (SELECT SUM(p2.cost)
                      FROM projects p2
                      WHERE p2.company_id = p.company_id
                      ORDER BY SUM(p2.cost) ASC
                      LIMIT 1
                     );
```

The two versions are subtly different:

- The first will always return one customer, even if there are ties.
- The first will convert the `company_id` to a string.
- The first can run into overflow conditions, because the length of the intermediate result for `group_concat()` is controlled by a system parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` and `ALL`

```
SELECT p.company_id, 
       p.customer_id, 
       SUM(p.cost) AS profit
FROM projects p
GROUP BY p.company_id, p.customer_id
HAVING SUM(p.cost) <= ALL(
   SELECT SUM(p2.cost)
   FROM projects p2
   WHERE p2.company_id = p.company_id
   GROUP BY p2.customer_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT customer_id
            , company_id
            , SUM(cost) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY customer_id
            , company_id
     ) a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT company_id
            , MIN(total) min_total 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT customer_id
                   , company_id
                   , SUM(cost) total 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY customer_id
                   , company_id
            ) x  
        GROUP 
           BY company_id
     ) b 
    ON b.company_id = a.company_id 
   AND b.min_total = a.total;
```